# 'Freeze panes'-style effect using CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

Is it possible/easy to create a web page which would act like a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet that has 'Freeze panes' applied to it? By this, I mean that a header and sidebar should remain fixed in their places but scroll down/right when the page is scrolled.

I need something like [this](http://www.coastworx.com/freezepains_table.html), except that I want it to be applied to a whole page and not a table.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Scrollable' areas and 'unscrollable' areas in a website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030210/scrollable-areas-and-unscrollable-areas-in-a-website)

Comment: This is not what I need.  What I'm after is a fixed header that will allow scrolling to the right, and a fixed left sidebar that will allow scrolling down.. I used the analogy of fixed panes in Excel because that is exactly how I want this to work.

Comment: I read your question now but your link for 'this' has been broken ! Can you directly insert your this in your question ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done in using `position: fixed` line in CSS class.

For example a `div` with the class

```css
#fixed-div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

will remain fixed in the upmost 100px of your browser viewport when you're scrolling.

This fiddle demonstrates the effect in both vertical and horizontal direction.
http://jsfiddle.net/ukzYf/1/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for `position: fixed`?

Here's a simple working example for you:

```css
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    margin: 50px 0 0 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.<br>
    Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat, arcu ante placerat erat, non tristique elit urna et turpis. Quisque mi metus, ornare sit amet fermentum et, tincidunt et orci. Fusce eget orci a orci congue vestibulum. Ut dolor diam, elementum et vestibulum eu, porttitor vel elit. Curabitur venenatis pulvinar tellus gravida ornare. Sed et erat faucibus nunc euismod ultricies ut id justo. Nullam cursus suscipit nisi, et ultrices justo sodales nec. Fusce venenatis facilisis lectus ac semper. Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bibendum purus convallis nulla ultrices ultricies. Nullam aliquam, mi eu aliquam tincidunt, purus velit laoreet tortor, viverra pretium nisi quam vitae mi. Fusce vel volutpat elit. Nam sagittis nisi dui.
    Suspendisse lectus leo, consectetur in tempor sit amet, placerat quis neque. Etiam luctus porttitor lorem, sed suscipit est rutrum non. Curabitur lobortis nisl a enim congue semper. Aenean commodo ultrices imperdiet. Vestibulum ut justo vel sapien venenatis tincidunt. Phasellus eget dolor sit amet ipsum dapibus condimentum vitae quis lectus. Aliquam ut massa in turpis dapibus convallis. Praesent elit lacus, vestibulum at malesuada et, ornare et est. Ut augue nunc, sodales ut euismod non, adipiscing vitae orci. Mauris ut placerat justo. Mauris in ultricies enim. Quisque nec est eleifend nulla ultrices egestas quis ut quam. Donec sollicitudin lectus a mauris pulvinar id aliquam urna cursus. Cras quis ligula sem, vel elementum mi. Phasellus non ullamcorper urna.<br>    
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In euismod ultrices facilisis. Vestibulum porta sapien adipiscing augue congue id pretium lectus molestie. Proin quis dictum nisl. Morbi id quam sapien, sed vestibulum sem. Duis elementum rutrum mauris sed convallis. Proin vestibulum magna mi. Aenean tristique hendrerit magna, ac facilisis nulla hendrerit ut. Sed non tortor sodales quam auctor elementum. Donec hendrerit nunc eget elit pharetra pulvinar. Suspendisse id tempus tortor. Aenean luctus, elit commodo laoreet commodo, justo nisi consequat massa, sed vulputate quam urna quis eros. Donec vel.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.<br>
    Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat, arcu ante placerat erat, non tristique elit urna et turpis. Quisque mi metus, ornare sit amet fermentum et, tincidunt et orci. Fusce eget orci a orci congue vestibulum. Ut dolor diam, elementum et vestibulum eu, porttitor vel elit. Curabitur venenatis pulvinar tellus gravida ornare. Sed et erat faucibus nunc euismod ultricies ut id justo. Nullam cursus suscipit nisi, et ultrices justo sodales nec. Fusce venenatis facilisis lectus ac semper. Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bibendum purus convallis nulla ultrices ultricies. Nullam aliquam, mi eu aliquam tincidunt, purus velit laoreet tortor, viverra pretium nisi quam vitae mi. Fusce vel volutpat elit. Nam sagittis nisi dui.<br>
    Suspendisse lectus leo, consectetur in tempor sit amet, placerat quis neque. Etiam luctus porttitor lorem, sed suscipit est rutrum non. Curabitur lobortis nisl a enim congue semper. Aenean commodo ultrices imperdiet. Vestibulum ut justo vel sapien venenatis tincidunt. Phasellus eget dolor sit amet ipsum dapibus condimentum vitae quis lectus. Aliquam ut massa in turpis dapibus convallis. Praesent elit lacus, vestibulum at malesuada et, ornare et est. Ut augue nunc, sodales ut euismod non, adipiscing vitae orci. Mauris ut placerat justo. Mauris in ultricies enim. Quisque nec est eleifend nulla ultrices egestas quis ut quam. Donec sollicitudin lectus a mauris pulvinar id aliquam urna cursus. Cras quis ligula sem, vel elementum mi. Phasellus non ullamcorper urna.<br>
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In euismod ultrices facilisis. Vestibulum porta sapien adipiscing augue congue id pretium lectus molestie. Proin quis dictum nisl. Morbi id quam sapien, sed vestibulum sem. Duis elementum rutrum mauris sed convallis. Proin vestibulum magna mi. Aenean tristique hendrerit magna, ac facilisis nulla hendrerit ut. Sed non tortor sodales quam auctor elementum. Donec hendrerit nunc eget elit pharetra pulvinar. Suspendisse id tempus tortor. Aenean luctus, elit commodo laoreet commodo, justo nisi consequat massa, sed vulputate quam urna quis eros. Donec vel.
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost it. I have an Excel workbook that I saved as a web document. The spreadsheet in the workbook contains a freeze pane at column B, row 3. Everything below row 3 scrolls vertically, everything right of column B scrolls horizontally. Columns A and B of rows 4 down do not scroll right or left, rows 1, 2 and 3 right of column B do not scroll up or down. Columns A and B of rows 1, 2 and 3 do not scroll at all. This is what I would like to duplicate, but Excel does not include CSS or HTML that does this. Manually editing the file is difficult, but can be done if I know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking something like this.

May be this can help: angular-table-freezepane
https://jatinmarwah.github.io/angular-table-freezepane/app/#/

Answer (score 1):

As known, the CSS rule

```
position: fixed;
```

applied to table headers usually breaks the match between them and the corresponding columns into the *tbody* part of the table, because it kind of "detaches" the targeted HTML element from the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) normal stream and makes it to act as an independent element. It means that if any of the table body text into any *[td](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td)* element is edited and the width of the corresponding column varies accordingly to the new text length, the *thead* doesn't stay in sync width it, generating bad columns alignment.
To solve it, you have to add a fixed width to each column to prevent broken layout due to columns misalignment.

So I would like to add a further CSS solution that doesn't have such a drawback:

```
.stickyClass > th
{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Insert the following code

```
class = "stickyClass"
```

into the HTML *[tr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)* element you what to target.

How does it work?
It will make all nested *[th](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th)* elements (header cells) to behave as usual until the scroll top indicated into the second CSS rule is achieved (it is possible to set a value different from 0 to match your needs). After that scroll amount, the element changes its behavior and act as a fixed element. The advantage of the sticky rule is that it keeps the *thead*-*tbody* columns width correspondence, so the table layout doesn't break even if the *td* content text is edited and changes the width of the column itself. So it is a great alternative to use in elastic table layouts.

Also, if you have a long document with a table and even other content, using the fixed CSS solution makes the table head to stay visible even on other content that isn't properly related. In other words, the fixed element of the table stays fixed and unscrollable even if that specific table isn't anymore the element visible on the screen because of scrolling the page itself over the table boundaries.

The sticky approach doesn't have this drawback, because the stuck element stays visible only until the related table (the main parent element) is visible on the screen. Once the relative table scrolls away and it isn't visible anymore, the stuck *head* element disappears accordingly. So you can have different content into the same page (normal text, paragraphs, images, and even more and more different tables) without creating any mess with elements not related that stay visible when they aren't really needed. Of course, with JavaScript you can fix this unwanted behavior of the "fixed" solution, but the "sticky" solution is simpler to implement and it acts even if the browser has JavaScript switched off.

Here you can have a look on the browser support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Drawback: unfortunately the sticky CSS rule doesn't work directly on *thead* and *tr* elements (it is still a little buggy), so you need to aim it to the th sub elements adding **> th** to the name of the class.

This means that this answer doesn't replace the others of this topic, but it integrates them, allowing you to choose the one that best fits your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something as demoed in [this fixed layout example](http://bpratik.in/dev/FixedLayout/layout.html).

If so, see [the code and tutorial here](http://www.innovativephp.com/fixed-positioning-html-elements-with-css-and-jquery/):

> We can make a html element fixed using the css position attribute. Also to make an element fixed we need to give the at least one coordinate point from top,left,bottom,right. The syntax for making a fixed position element is shown below. In these examples provided below i have used position fixed divs to display the elements in static position on window scroll.

```
.fixed_elements{
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
}
```

Comment: Hi bPratik, Stack Overflow answers are designed to be a resource of knowledge for years to come. If the links you provided were to ever break, your answer would be useless. I added some of the information from the link to your post to help make it more useful, and I've upvoted your post to counter the downvote it received from being a link-only answer. In the future, consider providing more context in your answer to avoid link-rot. Feel free to [edit] further if you think it can be improved even more. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks @jmort253, I meant to fix this after my meta post but got carried away in other things! thanks for your effort though!

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
tbody{
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 350px;
  width: 102%;
}
thead,tbody{
    display: block;
}
```

I define the columns width with bootstrap css col-md-xx. Without defining the columns width the auto-width of the  doesn't match the . The 102% percent is because you lose some sapce with the overflow