# Freezing panes via CSS: issue when resizing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a top, fixed pane showing logo, links etc. which should remain visible while scrolling.

I read [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030371/freeze-panes-style-effect-using-css-html) about how to do this, where one of the replies showed this code: http://jsfiddle.net/ukzYf/1/

This pane has some css buttons positioned in a single row (not within a table) which nicely stack when resizing the window.

The main problem is, since the frozen pane's height is in pixels, whenever the window is resized, the stacked buttons partially cover the text.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/tpvLeLL7/2/

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
.header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
}
.scrollable {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 205px 0 0 0;
}
.button {
  position: static;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 15px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
  background-color: #555555;
  color: white;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
}
```

```html
<div class='fixed header'>
  <h1 style="color:white;font-size:300%;text-align:center;margin-top:20px;">Fancy Title</h1>
  <div align="center">
    <button class="button">Button 1</button>
    <button class="button">Button 2</button>
    <button class="button">Button 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='scrollable'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet
  vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper
  sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis
  quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est. Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam
  velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat, arcu
  ante placerat erat, non tristique elit urna et turpis. Quisque mi metus, ornare sit amet fermentum et, tincidunt et orci. Fusce eget orci a orci congue vestibulum. Ut dolor diam, elementum et vestibulum eu, porttitor vel elit. Curabitur venenatis pulvinar
  tellus gravida ornare. Sed et erat faucibus nunc euismod ultricies ut id justo. Nullam cursus suscipit nisi, et ultrices justo sodales nec. Fusce venenatis facilisis lectus ac semper. Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bibendum purus convallis nulla ultrices
  ultricies. Nullam aliquam, mi eu aliquam tincidunt, purus velit laoreet tortor, viverra pretium nisi quam vitae mi. Fusce vel volutpat elit. Nam sagittis nisi dui. Suspendisse lectus leo, consectetur in tempor sit amet, placerat quis neque. Etiam luctus
  porttitor lorem, sed suscipit est rutrum non. Curabitur lobortis nisl a enim congue semper. Aenean commodo ultrices imperdiet. Vestibulum ut justo vel sapien venenatis tincidunt. Phasellus eget dolor sit amet ipsum dapibus condimentum vitae quis lectus.
  Aliquam ut massa in turpis dapibus convallis. Praesent elit lacus, vestibulum at malesuada et, ornare et est. Ut augue nunc, sodales ut euismod non, adipiscing vitae orci. Mauris ut placerat justo. Mauris in ultricies enim. Quisque nec est eleifend
  nulla ultrices egestas quis ut quam. Donec sollicitudin lectus a mauris pulvinar id aliquam urna cursus. Cras quis ligula sem, vel elementum mi. Phasellus non ullamcorper urna. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
  inceptos himenaeos. In euismod ultrices facilisis. Vestibulum porta sapien adipiscing augue congue id pretium lectus molestie. Proin quis dictum nisl. Morbi id quam sapien, sed vestibulum sem. Duis elementum rutrum mauris sed convallis. Proin vestibulum
  magna mi. Aenean tristique hendrerit magna, ac facilisis nulla hendrerit ut. Sed non tortor sodales quam auctor elementum. Donec hendrerit nunc eget elit pharetra pulvinar. Suspendisse id tempus tortor. Aenean luctus, elit commodo laoreet commodo, justo
  nisi consequat massa, sed vulputate quam urna quis eros. Donec vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec
  et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in
  urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem
  facilisis semper ac in est. Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id
  fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat, arcu ante placerat erat, non tristique elit urna et turpis. Quisque mi metus, ornare sit amet fermentum et, tincidunt et orci. Fusce eget orci a orci congue vestibulum. Ut dolor diam,
  elementum et vestibulum eu, porttitor vel elit. Curabitur venenatis pulvinar tellus gravida ornare. Sed et erat faucibus nunc euismod ultricies ut id justo. Nullam cursus suscipit nisi, et ultrices justo sodales nec. Fusce venenatis facilisis lectus
  ac semper. Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bibendum purus convallis nulla ultrices ultricies. Nullam aliquam, mi eu aliquam tincidunt, purus velit laoreet tortor, viverra pretium nisi quam vitae mi. Fusce vel volutpat elit. Nam sagittis nisi dui. Suspendisse
  lectus leo, consectetur in tempor sit amet, placerat quis neque. Etiam luctus porttitor lorem, sed suscipit est rutrum non. Curabitur lobortis nisl a enim congue semper. Aenean commodo ultrices imperdiet. Vestibulum ut justo vel sapien venenatis tincidunt.
  Phasellus eget dolor sit amet ipsum dapibus condimentum vitae quis lectus. Aliquam ut massa in turpis dapibus convallis. Praesent elit lacus, vestibulum at malesuada et, ornare et est. Ut augue nunc, sodales ut euismod non, adipiscing vitae orci. Mauris
  ut placerat justo. Mauris in ultricies enim. Quisque nec est eleifend nulla ultrices egestas quis ut quam. Donec sollicitudin lectus a mauris pulvinar id aliquam urna cursus. Cras quis ligula sem, vel elementum mi. Phasellus non ullamcorper urna. Class
  aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In euismod ultrices facilisis. Vestibulum porta sapien adipiscing augue congue id pretium lectus molestie. Proin quis dictum nisl. Morbi id quam sapien, sed vestibulum
  sem. Duis elementum rutrum mauris sed convallis. Proin vestibulum magna mi. Aenean tristique hendrerit magna, ac facilisis nulla hendrerit ut. Sed non tortor sodales quam auctor elementum. Donec hendrerit nunc eget elit pharetra pulvinar. Suspendisse
  id tempus tortor. Aenean luctus, elit commodo laoreet commodo, justo nisi consequat massa, sed vulputate quam urna quis eros. Donec vel.</div>
```

Is there any way to make the pane somewhat dynamic? I'd rather do this instead of forcing the buttons to stay fixed, but in case the fist is not possible, the latter would do. Although I would also need help with that.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to make those buttons like a responsive menu for the certain different window widths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media queries to change the height of the header.

```
header{
    height:250px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    header{
       height:200px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    header{
       height:150px;
   }
}
```

Comment: you can also set your fixed header to be dynamic height and then use javascript to set a decent padding top for the content that should show below the header.